# How do I prevent the java.lang.Numberformatexception Invalid Long: error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want my app to display time past on a textview e.g 3 mins ago. So I have a parse.com class that has a

```
public String get timestamp()
{ 
return get string("timestamp")
}
```

and a

```
public void set timestamp(String Value) 
{
put("timestamp",Value)
}
```

I have a postActivity that is sets the timestamp. First I got the current system time

```
Long time=System.currentTimeMilli(); String timeset = time.toString();
Post post = new Post();
post.set timestamp(timeset);
```

On my mainActivity where I retrieve my views, I have a

```
Textview time = (Textview) view.findViewById(R.id.txttime);
CharSequence timeAgo =  
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(post.getTimestamp()),
System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
time.setText(timeAgo);
```

I get the `java.lang.numberformatexception` when on `the(Long.parseLong(post.getTimestamp()))`

line How do I prevent it?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try converting a Timestamp to a long value and then converting back to a string.

E.g.

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
//now back to long
long timestampLong = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(ts.getTime()));
```